# Targeting a label using JQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm having trouble using JQuery to change the value of a label.  In particular:

```
<label for="answer[649][radiobutton_other_value]">Other:</label>
```

My goal is to change the value "Other:" to something else.  Is there any way to use "answer[649][radiobutton_other_value]" as an anchor to target the label?

Comment: Add an ID attribute to the label and that will help. No need for something convoluted like checking the for attribute.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm hacking an existing page, so I can't add an ID to the tag.  Otherwise I'd agree.  :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yes, just target the label with `label[for^="answer[649]"]`

```
$('label[for^="answer[649]"]').text('other value');
```

this will find a label whose `for` attribute is starting with `answer[649]` and will change its text

Comment: This worked perfect - thanks!  I didn't know about "^".  What does it do?

Comment: It will check for string matches starting with the keyword specified

Comment: @Anthony, I wrote it in my answer :)

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to select something by id that is above the label to narrow the scope if possible. Then do something like:

```
$("#ParentElem").find("label[for='answer[649][radiobutton_other_value]']").text("New Text Here");
```

If it's not possible to narrow the scope of the selector or it is a very small page then this will work:

```
$("label[for='answer[649][radiobutton_other_value]']").text("New Text Here");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('label[for*=answer]').html('New Value')
```

// OR

```
$('[label[for^=answer]').html('New Value')
```

// OR

```
$('label[for="answer[649][radiobutton_other_value]"]').html('New Value')
```

Comment: Sorry, you need to use `.html`, not `.val`

Comment: Thanks sushanth!  Looks like Fabrizio beat you to it, but you're otherwise correct.

Comment: @ianpgall good point but `.text` may be more appropriate if you know the exact usage. `.html` has some extra processing involved compared to `.text`. You of course would use `.html` if there is any possibility of more than plain text though.